# Execute SQL Plus Command in Golang

Tags: go, sqlplus

I need to run a .sql file in Golang with Sql Plus, which creates a table and a file named `tb_data_20180502104923`. I named the .sql script as `tb_data_20180502104923.sql` with contents as follows:

```
set headsep off
set pagesize 0
set trimspool on
set trimout on
create table tb_data_20180502104923
as
select * from tb_data;
spool tb_data_20180502104923.txt
SELECT data_id||';'||data_content FROM tb_data_20180502104923;
spool off
```

I have tried this with `os/exec` like this:

```
func main(){
    cmd := exec.Command("sqlplus -s admin/123#@172.10.1.211:1521/orcl < tb_data_20180502104923.sql")

    var out, stderr bytes.Buffer

    cmd.Stdout = &out
    cmd.Stderr = &stderr

    err := cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error executing query. Command Output: %+v\n: %+v, %v", out.String(), stderr.String(), err)
    }
}
```

Which return me an error message:

```
2018/05/02 11:06:46 Error executing query. Command Output: 
: , fork/exec sqlplus -s admin/123#@172.10.1.1:1521/orcl < tb_data_20180502104923.sql: no such file or directory
exit status 1
```

And if I change the `cmd := exec.Command` statement to:

```
cmd := exec.Command("sqlplus", "-s", "admin/123#@172.10.1.211:1521/orcl", "< tb_data_20180502104923.sql")
```

It return me nothing, and both tabel & file `tb_data_20180502104923` did not created.

Where did I do it wrong, or is using Sql Plus not possible in Golang? And if it's not possible, is there any other way to do what I need?

Comment: To run the command `sqlplus user/pass@connect @scriptname` in go, try `exec.Command("sqlplus", "user/pass@connect", "@scriptname")`

Comment: Thanks for your comment Mark, but I have solved my own question. It's just my poor understanding. I've post the solution of this problem below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allright, nevermind, looks like it's just my poor understanding on how to use `os/exec`.

So in case someone doesn't know how to use it, here how I solve my own problem.

I change

```
cmd := exec.Command("sqlplus", "-s", "admin/123#@172.10.1.211:1521/orcl", "< tb_data_20180502104923.sql")
```

to

```
cmd := exec.Command("bash", "-c", "sqlplus -s admin/123#@172.10.1.211:1521/orcl < tb_data_20180502104923.sql")
```

The first parameter `bash` is the kind of Shell you want to use,

the second parameter `-c` is the argument of `bash`,

and the third parameter is the `command` which I want to execute.

Well, correct me if I'm wrong.